# Crisp.chat how to register a callback event (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide/show an element when the chat gets opened or closed.
I don't understand how I should write the callback function that should trigger.

I want my element `$('.customtrigger')` to `.hide()` or `.show()`.

Documentation from Crisp.chat:
[Documentation](https://help.crisp.chat/en/article/how-to-use-dollarcrisp-javascript-sdk-10ud15y/)

> **chat:opened** - $crisp.push(["on", "chat:opened", callback]) - Handles the chatbox opened event (triggers your callback function)

I tried to contact Crisp.chat support but they could not provide examples and didn't understand my question?!

I think it's a simple jQuery question - I just don't understand how I should use it. hmm.

Comment: Could you please include your current code in the question so we can see the context you're working in. Their documentation seems straightforward. What part are you having an issue with, specifically? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for updating my question and for your feedback :) I have found the solution and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to be quite simple :)

I can fire some code like this when the chat gets open

```
function openchat() {
    $('.chattrigger').fadeOut( "slow" );
}
$crisp.push(["on", "chat:opened", openchat]);
```

And when the chat gets closed

```
function closechat() {
    $('.chattrigger').fadeIn( "slow" );
}
$crisp.push(["on", "chat:closed", closechat])
```

Sorry for my question :)

Hopefully someone can use my answer